# How to watch on tablet a movie stored on PC?

Tags: windows-10, video, android, network-shares, video-streaming

I have a movie stored on PC harddrive. I have an andriod tablet. How to watch that movie, but on a tablet? How to stream it? Its a windows 10 PC, and its configured for sharing but I dont know how the tablet can find the shared folders and click and play the movie. Kodi works, but Im looking for something simple, as Im not building an entertainment library, just a way to instantiously switch from PC to tablet.

edit: sounds straighforward, but for some reason cant find the answer to this. None of the apps I tried work to achieve this.

Comment: Are you able to view the shared directory on your tablet at all?  If so, viewing the directory with a file manager and opening the file might work.  I have a file server in my minivan with music and movies and the kids are able to access stuff with a file manager and just open it.

Comment: which file manager? i tried two and they didnt find the shared directory and they such a hassle to use.

Comment: It has problems, but at least for a test, ES File Explorer seems to work.  I'm not sure what my kids use these days.

Comment: This is a duplicate, but the OP may not know the underlying search terms to bring it up. This big hiccup is always the "network share." Android requires a samba-capable client to browse windows shares. ES File explorer can do this, and there are a number of open source media players that also handle this. Some, like VLC also can read from ISO.